# TranslateModule and TranslationPipe is not working anymore in Angular2 Final

Tags: angular, ionic2

### app.module.ts

```
import {
  TranslatePipe,
  TranslateModule,
  TranslateService,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateStaticLoader,
  MissingTranslationHandler
} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}),
        HttpModule,
         TranslateModule.forRoot({
             provide: TranslateLoader,
             useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, "../../www/assets/i18n", ".json"),
             deps: [Http]
         }),
        StoreModule.provideStore(rootReducer)
    ]..
```

### Error

Above does not work with ng2-final. I get:

```
03:26:44]  ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 98:25 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/me/devel/mega-project/.tmp/app/app.module.ts
```

### Expected behaviour

Implementation should work like before on RC4, e.g.:

```
 <div style="text-transform:none">{{ "§GLOBAL.PHONE_CALL_FREE" | translate }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.)** Pull 3.1.0 of ng-translate or later where they implemented ng2 AoT compatibility and meta information.

**2.)** Then Use

```
import {TranslateModule, TranslateStaticLoader} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import {TranslateLoader} from "ng2-translate";

export function translateLoaderFactory(http: any) {
  return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
    provide: TranslateLoader,
       useFactory: translateLoaderFactory,
       deps: [Http]
   }),
```

**3.)** If not working, follow up on other steps from this thread:

https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/218