# ionic2 with ng2-translate throws compilation error

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-translate

I am building an Ionic2 app and trying to use ng2-translate for localization. I followed https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/ng2-translate/ this tutorial.

However it gives me some compilation errors as follows:

[image]

because of these app can not start. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';`
 to `import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate'`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was incomplete imports which aren't mentioned in the tutorial I followed!

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {TranslateLoader} from 'ng2-translate';
```

this solved the problem. I refereed ([TranslateModule and TranslationPipe is not working anymore in Angular2 Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927785/translatemodule-and-translationpipe-is-not-working-anymore-in-angular2-final))